# What is the best way to send an email from a batch file?

Tags: windows, email, batch-file

I have a nightly batch job that can tell if it has failed. I want it to send me an email, possibly with an attachment when it does.

How can I send an email from a Windows Batch (.bat) file?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If the SMTP-server that is a part of IIS is installed, you could use the Echo command to write a file to the pickup folder, and it'll get sent.

```
echo From: test@example.com>tmp.txt
echo To: test@example.com>>tmp.txt
echo Subject: hello>>tmp.txt
echo.>>tmp.txt
echo Hello world>>tmp.txt
copy tmp.txt \Inetpub\mailroot\Pickup
```

Comment: How would you do an attachment?

Comment: This isn't the way if you want attachment, use Blat or something. (Something could be running a VBScript calling CDOSYS.)

Answer (score 4):

[Blat](http://www.blat.net/). Nothing more needs to be said. ;)