# Cruise versus TeamCity versus CruiseControl.net

Tags: continuous-integration

We are using CruiseControl.net and we are looking into moving to team city but i just noticed that thoughtworks has another product called Cruise

http://studios.thoughtworks.com/cruise-continuous-integration

is anyone using this product in a production environment and if so do they have an opinion on this product versus team city

Answer (score 5, accepted):

We use TeamCity in our company and we are very satisfied with it. It's easy to configure, has a clean UI and quite simple to manage. Additionally the VS-Addin is quiet comfortable. Only the 'Automatically commit after successfull build' does not work correctly.

I also used CC.Net, but I was missing 
- easy config
- authentication
- clean ui

Maybe atlassians 'Bamboo' is another possible CI-Server. Check it out.

Answer (score 2):

I worked in a team where we used Cruise and my history had been with CruiseControl.NET.

Functionality wise I couldn't see that much difference between the two, however the Cruise product has significantly more 'polish' from a UI and usability perspective.

Cruise seemed to hold your hand in some of the configuration details, the upside I guess is a standardised approach across all projects. However, I did feel as if some of this hand-holding was forcing you to configure your project somewhat around the product. I'm always a bit skeptical of this.

Just my two cents comparing Cruise / CruiseControl.NET.

Hope this was helpful.

Answer (score 1):

Also see this SO question: [CruiseControl [.Net] vs TeamCity for continuous integration?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/195835/cruisecontrol-net-vs-teamcity-for-continuous-integration)