# CruiseControl.NET and svn

Tags: svn, cruisecontrol.net

i am new to cruisecontrol.net and wanted to set it up to work with our svn repository. I installed cuisecontrol 1.4.4 and i created ccnet.confi which looks like this

```
<cruisecontrol xmlns:cb="urn:ccnet.config.builder">
<!-- This is your CruiseControl.NET Server Configuration file. Add your projects below! -->
<project name="HelloWorld">
    <sourcecontrol type="svn" autoGetSource="true">
        <trunkUrl>svn://svn.mycompany.at/trunk/</trunkUrl>
       <workingDirectory>C:\cruisecontrol\server\helloworld\WorkingDirectory</workingDirectory>
        <username>username</username>
        <password>password</password>
    </sourcecontrol>
</project>
```

but when i start ccne.exe i get this message

```
[helloworld:INFO] Integrator for project: helloworld is now stopped.
[helloworld:INFO] Starting integrator for project: helloworld
```

and nothing else happens (no errors or warnings or anything else), I checked folder Artifacts but it is empty, I tried this on server 2008 and server 2003, with ccnet 1.4.4 and 1.4.4.sp1, i also tried checking repository out to my working directory manually but this did  not change a thing. I also tried adding following xml elements

```
<checkExternals>True</checkExternals> 
<checkExternalsRecursive>True</checkExternalsRecursive>
```

but that did not work either.

Please note this is my complete config file and I do not have anything else in there currently, as I was hoping just to get it check my things out of svn-repository.

what am I doing wrong

thanks

Comment: You are filling in a valid username and password right? Sorry, I felt I had to ask just in case.

Comment: yes, I tried it also with wrong but still did not get any response that which bodered me

Comment: i moved to version 1.3 and it started working, it seams that checkout is symply not triggered in 1.4, am I missing some config node for 1.4?

Comment: you just might want to look at this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/195835/cruisecontrol-net-vs-teamcity-for-continuous-integration

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the problem is trigger element, in the version prior to 1.4.3 default (if no trigger) was that  interval trigger with default settings would be created (firing every 60 seconds), and in versions after no triggers would be fired so nothing happend

http://confluence.public.thoughtworks.org/display/CCNET/Trigger+Blocks

so I added trigger and it worked

bye

Answer (score 2):

Unless you've deliberatly missed out part of your config file, it's incomplete. All you've told it so far is that you have a project and it's in source control. You need to tell cc.net waht to do with it, how to build it and when to build it.

You need to add some tasks that you actually want to occur when you do a build, and then you need to add some triggers for those tasks.

(Sorry if you have done this stuff and just didn't bother including it all in the question)

Comment: no i did not include it, as i was just trying to get files to my local machine, build would be simply next phase, but as it is not checking out files there is no need for me to build it yet :), but thanks

Answer (score 0):

It has been a long time since I used Cruise Control.net. But there used to be an issue with it's svn integration. You had to check out to the working directory once manually (using the svn command line or tortoise) before cc.net would do it's thing right. This was years ago so it might be fixed, but it is easy enough to try.

Comment: i tried that: "i also tried checking repository out to my working directory manually but this did not change a thing"