# Cruise Control.Net best practices

Tags: svn, continuous-integration, cruisecontrol.net

I'm going to implement a CI process with CC.NET so I'm looking for best practices for CC.net implementation.

I use SVN as source control and JIRA as an issue tracker (if it's a useful tip).

Any recommandation or article suggestion will be appreciated.

Note: I read [this article by Martin Fowler](http://martinfowler.com/articles/continuousIntegration.html).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can start by going through the best practices that Thoughtworks themselves have compiled - [CC.NET Best Practices](http://confluence.public.thoughtworks.org/display/CC/CruiseControlBestPractices).  From there, I would recommend the documentation provided by Thoughtworks.  Just go down the list in the "Getting Started" section under the "For Users" heading.  Yes, it's an overview, but you have to start somewhere and where better to start than with the basics.  After that, Google is your best friend.  You might also want to look up your local .NET User Group through ineta.org; these groups can be invaluable sources of information on programming in .NET environments.

Answer (score 1):

I know that you've said that you're going to use CC.NET but I would be tempted to look at [TeamCity](http://www.jetbrains.com/teamcity/) by JetBrains the guys produce [Resharper](http://www.jetbrains.com/resharper/). I have used CC.NET in the past, but when I used TeamCiy for the first time I was very impressed.

Comment: Why do you recommand teamCity, Just because of UI or any other advantages?

Comment: TeamCity didn't even install on our buildserver. I didn't have the time nor the stamina to check what was wrong but in sharp contrast, Hudson installed without any hickup. That being said, I do believe TeamCity would be the more user-friendly one of the two.

Comment: @dave - but TeamCity is not free, CC.NET is Free and open source. we have 10 active developer and teamcity just support 3 agent. I think it is better to extend CC.NET and create a UI for it.

Comment: @Nasser - The free version of TeamCity actually allows 20 user accounts. The 3 agents are the number of build process that can be concurrently running builds. I understand that you may want to stick to open source, but I have to say that in this instance, the quality of the UI and the productivity gains I achieved meant that I would use it again. Behind the scenes, TeamCity can use various build tools to execute the build such as NAnt and MSBuild so you are still free to fully integrate with existing processes.

Comment: @Nasser - This may help with your decision http://stackoverflow.com/questions/195835/cruisecontrol-net-vs-teamcity-for-continuous-integration/196425#196425

Comment: Love TeamCity.. and with TeamCity, we setup a build agent on a virtual box to delegate the acceptance tests to. We have both CCNet and TeamCity running... we sort of use TeamCity (free version)internal to our project.